# How can I solve this Iterated integral

Tags: integration, iterated-integrals

[domain E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQv2r.gif)

I've this integral on the domain E: x[0,1], y=x^2

$\int_E x^3sin(xy)\, dxdy$

I dont know how can I solve this through the two different ways:first integration in dx and then in dy, and viceversa.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain is: E={ $(x,y) | x\in [0,1], \ 0<y<x^2 $}

Your integral is easier to integrate first in y:

$\begin{align} I &=\int_0^1 \int_0^{x^2} x^3 \sin(xy)\ \mathrm{dy\  dx} \\
 &=\int_0^1 [-x^2 \cos(xy)]_0^{x^2}\ \mathrm{  dx} \\ 
 &=\int_0^1 -x^2 \cos(x^3)+x^2\ \mathrm{  dx} \\ 
 &=[-\frac 13 \sin(x^3)]_0^1+[\frac{x^3}3]_0^1\ \mathrm{  dx} \\ 
 &=\frac{1-\sin(1)}3\\ 
\end{align} 
$